# How to pass data from NSObject to another ViewController when click on TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, swift4

I have a `ViewController1` with a `TableView` inside. What I want to do is go to `ViewController2` and pass a piece of data along at the same time when user click on a `TableViewCell`.

**For more details :**

Each Cell have a `itemId` and other data which is store in `NSObject` class after pull from my API,which I use the data in `TableViewCell` class.So when I `performSegue` to `ViewController2`,I want to get the `itemId` in `ViewController2`

For now I able to go to `ViewController2` when click on a `tableViewCell` by using this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //here I dont know how to get the itemId for that particular cell
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSecondVc", sender: self)
}
```

I know I can pass my `itemId` like this:

```
var itemId : Int!
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "GoToSecondVc" , let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController{
  secondVC.itemId = self.itemId
}
```

**The problem for now** is I dont know how to get the `itemId` from `NSObject` when user click on any `tableViewCell` before I `performSegue` in `didSelectRowAt` section.

So how can I get the `itemId` in this case? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: put some code of cellForRowAtIndex and dataArrray...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to pass the selected index path in `didSelectRowAt` as `sender`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSecondVc", sender: indexPath)
}
```

And use it in `prepare(for segue`, a temporary variable `itemId` is not needed. The code assumes that `items` is the data source array:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "GoToSecondVc" , let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
         let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
         let item = items[indexPath.row]
         secondVC.itemId = item.itemId
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let it = dataArrray[indexPath.row] as! ItemType
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSecondVc", sender: it.itemID)
}
```